# Accessing multiple array elements for JS if/else

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gq0t4j93/51/
showing my page that I'm having an issue with trying to access different levels of arrays.

I had this working with simple ternary operation but my newly added if/else statements cause nothing to show now.

If you look in the JS of the fiddle you'll see I have a commented out section of ternary operators

```
    //   fullContent.innerHTML = '';
//   rightContent.innerHTML = '';
//   leftContent.innerHTML = '';

// fullContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 1 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : fullContent.innerHTML;

// leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : leftContent.innerHTML;

// rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 3 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : rightContent.innerHTML;
```

Here's a fiddle of it working just with ternary operators http://jsfiddle.net/gq0t4j93/55/

WHen those are in place and I remove the section of if/else above it, it works as expected. But I need to use if else statements to decide what content to put in what div, depending on page and panel types.

I'm trying to get it set so that "if the page_type_id of the top level (page_id) array is n, then check panel types of each content element for that page. if n, put in this div, if x put in that div"

All I really need to figure out here is how to access this properly so that on each iteration, I check page_type_id so I know what DIVS to hide, and then panel_type_id so I know which content to put in which div.

```js
const original_json = [{
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "86",
    "panel_type_id": "2",
    "cont_id": "138",
    "contID": "138",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "94",
    "page_type_id": "1",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "1",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "95",
    "page_type_id": "1",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "1",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page 2<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
    {
    "pageID": "96",
    "page_type_id": "1",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "1",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page 3<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
];

let counter = 0;

var fullContent = document.getElementById('fullContent');
var leftContent = document.getElementById('leftContent');
var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');

var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
var leftColumn = document.getElementById('leftColumn');
var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn');


// loop through original json
// for each item, get page ID and see if we've already created a new Page object for it
// if we have, add the object from the original json to the "content" array of the new page object
// otherwise, create a new Page object to put in our new array
const pages_array = original_json.reduce(function(pages_array, item, index, original_json) {
  const current_pageID = item.pageID;
  const exisiting_page = pages_array.find(page => page.pageID === current_pageID);

  if (exisiting_page === undefined) {
    const new_Page = {
      pageID: current_pageID,
      content: [item]
    }
    pages_array.push(new_Page);
  } else {
    exisiting_page.content.push(item)
  }

  return pages_array;
}, []);

// Open console to see data
console.clear();
console.log(pages_array); //this prints correct array

setInterval(() => { //here I loop through pages, but i need to loop within here over content to render html
  const currentJSONobject = pages_array[counter];
for(var i = 0; i < currentJSONobject.content.length; i++){

    
        if(currentJSONobject.content[i].page_type_id == 1){
            
            leftColumn.style.display = "none";
            rightColumn.style.display = "none";
            leftColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
            rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
            rightColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
            leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";

            if(currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 1){
                fullcontent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
            }

        }else if(currentJSONobject.content[i].page_type_id == 2){
            
            fullColumn.style.display = "none";
            leftColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
            rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
            rightColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
            leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";

            if(currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2){
                leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
            }else if(currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 3){
                rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
            }
        }


    //   fullContent.innerHTML = '';
    //   rightContent.innerHTML = '';
    //   leftContent.innerHTML = '';

    // fullContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 1 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : fullContent.innerHTML;
    
    // leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : leftContent.innerHTML;
    
    // rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 3 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : rightContent.innerHTML;

    }


  console.log(pages_array[counter])

  counter += 1;
  if (counter === pages_array.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

}, 1500)
```

```html
<div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
  
  <div class="col-lg-6 fullColumn">

    <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Half Page Divs -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn">

    <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn">

    <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- End Half Page Divs -->

</div>
<!-- End Row Middle -->
```

Comment: It'd be a lot better to post all the relevant code *here* and not just in the fiddle.

Comment: Just added the fiddle code into a snippet here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your console for errors, most of the time you'll find a relevant error stack printed. The problem is here:

```
var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
var leftColumn = document.getElementById('leftColumn');
var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn');
```

and here

```
<div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn">
  <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
  </div>
</div>
```

You are querying by ID where you html uses classes (e.g. `leftColumn`). Use `querySelector/querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` or set the right IDs to your html elements.

Also there are a few undefined variables such as `leftColumnQtr` from which you are trying to access the style attribute of an undefined variable.

See updated working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gq0t4j93/74/

Comment: Oh you mean for the columns? At first I didn't understand because I am using class and ID for the content div, but no IDs frot he column divs

Comment: Sorry can you check http://jsfiddle.net/gq0t4j93/61/  I resolved those errors but after the first iteration it still doesn't seem to show anything

Comment: The first one seems to work fine but it's just blankk after that and I wonder if it's something to do with my if/else statements

Comment: Problems are with your `style.display = "none"`. Once you hide them, you never unhide them. Also, you had weird nested conditionals where `page_id == 3` could never be reached because it was inside `page_id == 2` conditional. Make sure you indent your code correctly for readability to avoid making such mistakes. See updated http://jsfiddle.net/gq0t4j93/74/.